# Different names for "Birchas Kohanim"

Tags: tefilla, blessing, birchas-kohanim

Where did the different names for the "priestly blessings" come from?

Duchaning , Birkas Kohanim, Nesiat Kapayim etc..

Comment: All in the Mishna in one form or another. Except it's *oleh al haduchan*, "ascends onto the platform", that we somehow verbed.

Comment: [Duchen is the Aramaic word for the platform that is in front of the Aron Kodesh](https://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/duchaning/). Birkas Kohanim is literally Priestly Blessing and has  Sephardic roots.

Comment: Thank you, Please put it in answer form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Duchanen**

[According to Rabbi Yirmiyohu Kaganoff](https://rabbikaganoff.com/tag/duchaning/), duchaning has Aramaic roots and refers to the platform that is in front of the Aron Kodesh.

The Duchan, דוכן, which can for example be found in the [Mishnah in Middos 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.2.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), is referring to a three-staired platform

> there was a step a cubit high on which a platform was placed, and it had three steps each of half a cubit in height.

The Duchan is numbered "12" in the following picture [(Akiva Males from Torah Musings)](https://www.torahmusings.com/2015/06/what-does-the-duchan-have-to-do-with-birkas-kohanim/):

[image]

Rabbi Akiva Males has an interesting explanation on why Birkas Kohanim is also referred to as duchan. He writes:

> In order for Kohanim to enter the Ezras Kohanim to engage in any aspect of the Avodah, it was necessary to first ascend the Duchan by way of the Ezras Yisroel.

**Nesiat Kapayim**

Nesiat Kapayim, נשיאת כפים, literally means "raising the hands [to bless]". See for example Shulchan Aruch [(Orach Chaim 128:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128.1?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Taanis 26b](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.26b.8?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). The Midrash [(Sifrei Bamidbar 39:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Bamidbar.39.1?vhe=Wikisource&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes the reason behind nesiat kapayim:

> Blessing is likened to ministering. Just as ministering is standing, so, blessing. "Thus shall you bless the children of Israel": with raised hands. You say, with raised hands; but perhaps either with or without raised hands is permitted. It is, therefore, written (Vayikra 9:22) "And Aaron lifted his hands to the people and he blessed them." Just as there, with raised hands, so, here. R. Yonathan says: But perhaps just as there, Rosh Chodesh, offering, and the high-priest, so, here (these elements must obtain)!

My apologies. I did not find a good source describing the origins of the word birkas kohanim. Might add that in later.

Comment: "Duchanen" would be the more authentic term.

Comment: Birkath Kohanim (ברכת כהנים) is how the [Mishnah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.7.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) refers to it... it's also how I think most people would intuitively describe the miswah as articulated in [Numbers 6:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.23?lang=bi&aliyot=0)